# TFS Do Feature work items use time tracking and additional states?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

is it incorrect practice to add additional states and time tracking to the feature work item types?  I read that the time tracking fields are available in tasks, i don't see anyone trying to add it to features.  Our BA and Dev find that time tracking at the task level to be overkill.   i presume additional states is fine, but maybe we are not thinking of features in the right way.

Comment: what do you mean by time tracking?  Tasks have work remaining field which is primarily used for reporting progress - not for time tracking.

Comment: well i'm referring to estimate/remaining/total ... our BAs were trying to push 'task' related features to the feature level... just trying to understand what the proper practice is.